# Difference between library class and program class for Android Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm suddenly having a bunch of warnings about library class depending on program class while trying to build my release APK with proguard.

```
Warning: library class org.** depends on program class org.**
```

What is compiler referring to with `library class` and `program class`? I'm checking the classes out and they are all NOT mine, they are from the libraries I'm using. So what is it that the compiler is telling me?

Also, any ideas on how to fixes these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the warning message and [its documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#dependency) could be worded better. Roughly speaking, in this case "program classes" means "classes proguard thinks it's supposed to obfuscate" and "library classes" means "classes in another jar that use the to-be-obfuscated classes". It thinks you want to obfuscate those 3rd party jars, and doing so naively would introduce deployment risks.

Try adding the non-obfuscated 3rd party jars to the `-libraryjars` list to tell it to not obfuscate them.